# How to calculate integral, numerically, in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, integral

I've searched for an hour for the methods doing numerical integration. I'm new to `Rcpp` and rewriting my old programs now. What I have done in R was:

```
   x=smpl.x(n,theta.true)   
   joint=function(theta){# the joint dist for
                         #all random variable
     d=c()
     for(i in 1:n){
       d[i]=den(x[i],theta)
     }
     return(prod(d)*dbeta(theta,a,b))   }  
 joint.vec=Vectorize(joint)##vectorize the function, as required when
                           ##using integrate()   
margin=integrate(joint.vec,0,1)$value # the
                                ##normalizeing constant at the donominator  
 area=integrate(joint.vec,0,theta.true)$value # the values at the
                                              ## numeritor
```

- The `integrate()` function in R will be slow, and since I am doing the integration for a posterior distribution of a sample of size n, the value of the integration will be huge with large error.
- I am trying to rewrite my code with the help of `Rcpp`, but I　don't know how to deal with the integrate. Should I include a `c++ h file`? Or any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/yixuan/RcppNumerical

Answer (score 0):

You can code your function in `C` and call it, for instance, via the `sourceCpp` function and then `integrate` it in `R`. In alternative, you can call the integrate function of `R` within your `C` code by using the `Function` macro of `Rcpp`. See Dirk's book (Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp) on page 56 for an example of how to call `R` functions from `C`. Another alternative (which I believe is the best for most cases) is to integrate your function written in `C` , directly in `C`, using the `RcppGSL` package.

As about the huge normalizing constant, sometimes it is better to scale the function at the mode before integrating it (you can find modes with, e.g., `nlminb`, `optim`, etc.). Then, you integrate the rescaled function and to recover the original nroming constant multiply the resulting normalizing constant by the rescaling factor. Hope this may help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I coded the integrate function by my own in C++ and it's over 50 times faster..... however, I met some new problems. Do you still have any advice? I've posted my solution up there.

Comment: @user3518214 as I wrote you above, it is best (less error-prone) to code only your 'joint' function in C++, call it from R and just use integrate. If your function is not heavily oscillating (in your case I don't think it is!) R's integrate function will be extremely accurte! Besides, if integrate is slow it is mostly because your function is slow. As about integration limits check the modes of your function. If the modes are not on the border,  it is likely that the tails of the function will not matter so much so you can take as integration limits [1e-5, 9e-5] ...

Comment: in my previous comment  [1e-5,9e-5] -> [1e-5, 0.9999].

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe I missed your point last time. I will try your suggestion right away.  And actually, for different parameters of my function 'joint', the mode will be at the boundary. So maybe R's integrate has a better way dealing with that.

Comment: I just tried your idea. I coded my 'joint' function in C++, and use the integrate() in R, and it's really fast. However, I met a problem when trying to call integrate() in Cpp. I checked the book, and here is my code:   ' Rcpp::Function integrate("integrate");' I put this statement in the global environment. Then I used as : 'double margin = integrate(joint_cpp2,0,theta_true,n=n,x=x,a=a,b=b);' The problem is the the integrate function in in R returns a list. I tried to use : List margin, to catch the result and access the value by margin['value']. But they didn't work.

Comment: Calling R funcionts within C is time consuming. However, send me your code or give a reproduceble example so that I can try myself.

Answer (score 0):

after reading your @utobi advice, I felt programming by my own maybe easier. I simply use Simpson formula to approximate the integral:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double den_cpp (double x, double theta){
return(2*x/theta*(x<=theta)+2*(1-x)/(1-theta)*(theta<x));
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double joint_cpp ( double theta,int n,NumericVector x, double a, double b){
double val = 1.0;
NumericVector d(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
double tmp = den_cpp(x[i],theta);
val = val*tmp;
}
val=val*R::dbeta(theta,a,b,0);
return(val);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Cov_rate_raw ( double theta_true,  int n, double a, double b,NumericVector x){
//This function is used to test, not used in the fanal one
int steps = 1000;
double s = 0;
double start = 1.0e-4;
std::cout<<start<<" ";
double end = 1-start;
std::cout<<end<<" ";
double h = (end-start)/steps;
std::cout<<"1st h ="<<h<<" ";
double area = 0;
double margin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < steps ; i++){
double at_x = start+h*i;
double f_val = (joint_cpp(at_x,n,x,a,b)+4*joint_cpp(at_x+h/2,n,x,a,b)+joint_cpp(at_x+h,n,x,a,b))/6;
s = s + f_val;
}
margin = h*s;
s=0;
h=(theta_true-start)/steps;
std::cout<<"2nd h ="<<h<<" ";
for (int i = 0; i < steps ; i++){
double at_x = start+h*i;
double f_val = (joint_cpp(at_x,n,x,a,b)+4*joint_cpp(at_x+h/2,n,x,a,b)+joint_cpp(at_x+h,n,x,a,b))/6;
s = s + f_val;
}
area = h * s;
double r = area/margin;
int cover = (r>=0.025)&&(r<=0.975);
List ret;
ret["s"] = s;
ret["margin"] = margin;
ret["area"] = area;
ret["ratio"] = r;
ret["if_cover"] = cover;
return(ret);
}
```

I'm not that good at c++, so the two **for** loops like kind of silly.

It generally works, but there are still several potential problems:

1. I don't really know how to choose the steps, or how many sub intervals do I need to approximate the integrals. I've taken numerical analysis when I was an undergraduate, I think maybe I need to check my book about the expression of the error term, to decide the step length.
2. I compared my results with those from R. the integrate() function in R can take care of the integral over the interval [0,1]. That helps me because my function is undefined at 0 or 1, which takes infinite value. In my C++ code, I can only make my interval from [1e-4, 1-1e-4]. I tried different values like 1e-7, 1e-10, however, 1e-4 was the one most close to R's results....What should I do with it?