# Rcpp: call an R function from the Global Environment and use it in the C++ code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

How can I call an R function that does not belong to any R package into a C++ code?. I can show you what I mean through a very semplicistic example. Suppose I have an R file where I write

```
myRfunction <- function(x){
 return(x+2)
}
```

and I want to use it in a generic c++ code. So, I write something like

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec myCppfunction(arma::vec y){
 arma::sec results = myRfunction(y);  /* Or whatever I have to do to call it! */
 return results;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do it? What is the general procedure? Thank you all.

Comment: Other duplicates:

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463754/calling-r-function-from-rcpp 

and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016851/call-r-functions-in-rcpp

Answer (score 3):

Example. In R:

```
> timesTwoR <- function(x) 2*x
```

The `cpp` file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

Function timesTwoFromR = Environment::global_env()["timesTwoR"];

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return timesTwoFromR(x);
}
```

Then, in R:

```
> timesTwo(42)
[1] 84
```

Comment: Yep, as document. I'd move the function assignment inside the C++ function though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can pass the R function as an argument to the C++ function, something like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector call_r_fun(NumericVector x, Function f) {
  return f(x) ;
}
```