# how to speed up a bootstrapped vector generation in R

Tags: r, performance, data.table

### Toy data.table

Consider this data.table

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(data.table,magrittr,dplyr,glue)

dt <- data.table(x = c(1,3,4,5,8,12,13,20,21,25), 
           y = c(1,1,2,2,8,2,4,6,5,5),keep.rownames = T)
dt[,newval:=NA_real_]
dt[,rn:=as.integer(rownames(dt))]
dt[1,newval:=y] 
dt[,x_pre := shift(x,n = 1)]
dt[,x_nxt := shift(x,n = -1)]
setcolorder(dt,"rn")
dt[]
#>     rn  x y newval x_pre x_nxt
#>  1:  1  1 1      1    NA     3
#>  2:  2  3 1     NA     1     4
#>  3:  3  4 2     NA     3     5
#>  4:  4  5 2     NA     4     8
#>  5:  5  8 8     NA     5    12
#>  6:  6 12 2     NA     8    13
#>  7:  7 13 4     NA    12    20
#>  8:  8 20 6     NA    13    21
#>  9:  9 21 5     NA    20    25
#> 10: 10 25 5     NA    21    NA

# note the last 2 columns are simply the shifted values of x
```

### Use of for loop

The following is an inefficient function using `for` loop in R for bootstrapping a data.tale column.

```r
# function using a for loop on each observation
 func_loop <- function(dt){
   # create a for loop for updating the newval column iteratively
   for(i in seq_len(nrow(dt))[-c((nrow(dt) - c(0:1)))]){
     dt[i + 2,newval:=y] # temporary value to be erased later
     dt[,new_pre:=shift(newval, n = 1)]
     dt[,new_nxt:=shift(newval, n = -1)]
     # the following line of code uses the previously computed value (new_pre)
     dt[rn > 1,newval:=ifelse(rn==i+1, new_pre + (new_nxt - new_pre)* (x - x_pre) /((x_nxt - x_pre)),newval) ]
     dt[rn==i+2,newval:=NA_real_]
   }
   dt
 }
```

### Call the `for - loop` function

```r
 # call the function 
 func_loop(dt)[]
#>     rn  x y   newval x_pre x_nxt  new_pre  new_nxt
#>  1:  1  1 1 1.000000    NA     3       NA 1.666667
#>  2:  2  3 1 1.666667     1     4 1.000000 1.833333
#>  3:  3  4 2 1.833333     3     5 1.666667 3.375000
#>  4:  4  5 2 3.375000     4     8 1.833333 2.785714
#>  5:  5  8 8 2.785714     5    12 3.375000 3.757143
#>  6:  6 12 2 3.757143     8    13 2.785714 4.037500
#>  7:  7 13 4 4.037500    12    20 3.757143 4.879688
#>  8:  8 20 6 4.879688    13    21 4.037500       NA
#>  9:  9 21 5 4.903750    20    25 4.879688 5.000000
#> 10: 10 25 5       NA    21    NA       NA       NA

# benchmark the speed
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(func_loop(dt))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  func_loop(dt) 23.00165 24.24735 26.19917 25.11379 27.11327 39.43801   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Expectedly this gives a terrible efficiency of 30 msec for 10 rows, which means for a million rows it will take 50 minutes. I have several million rows to be computed.

I am aware of `froll*` series and use them extensively but here I am unable to apply `frollapply`, since this algo has a dependency on previous computation.

I have tried `data.table::set` also and that does'nt reduce drastically the time due to the fact that we have to call `dt[]` repeatedly which is an expensive call. See Henrik's comments below.

I am looking to improve the performance by several orders of magnitude and not just 20 or 40%. I would expect a 1/10th or 1/50th of the current response times with a good vector algorithm.

Comment: In your code any benefit of using `set` is lost because you call `[data.table` (`dt[`) in each iteration, which has a large overhead. I think your post would benefit from an explanation in words what you try to achieve and a demonstration on a small (10-ish rows) data set. Then it's much easier for people to try out alternatives, which can be applied to larger data. That said, it _seems_ like you want to do calculations on a moving window (`rn + 1:10`).  If so, `shift` may be an alternative. E.g. sum the two next (leading) values in a vector: ``Reduce(`+`, shift(v, 1:2, type = "lead"))``

Comment: I just saw that what I wrote above is also described in `?set`:  "[with `set`] overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided ... However, normally, we call `[.data.table` *once* on *large* data, not many times on small data.", which unfortunately happens in your loop (and in the various `*apply` "loops" in the current answer)

Comment: Now that @Henrik explained the limitations of `set()`, it sounds a bit like an (possible) XY-problem. You discard the `frollsum/-apply`-family, but this is exactly what gives you the major performance boost you are looking for (at least in this toy-example). Om my system, the above `for` loop takes 1.2 seconds, and the `frollsum`-alternative takes 400 *micro*-seconds. Can you eleborate more on your production-data, and why an froll-approach is not feasible?

Comment: what I mean is; why should `dt[, newval2 := shift(frollsum(value < 90, n = 10, align = "left"), n = 1, type = "lead")])` not work? Runtime: `0.000478` seconds.. Looks like there is a lot to be gained when able to code towards the `froll`-approach.

Comment: I have made changes to the code to make it closer to the production code. You will see why `frollapply` is not feasible here (or atleast I am unable to utilise it).  I need the values to be iteratively using the previous values. In an `frollapply` or any vector solution e.g. `shift` all values are computed simultaneously. I am posting the updated question now. And `frollapply `/` shift` based solutions are also welcome, as ideally they will be the fastest.

Comment: Dear all, after your feedback I have reduced the complexity of the reprex drastically. Hopefully now it can be addressed by many people easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `Rcpp` function will be much faster.

```
library(data.table)

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "NumericVector iterInterp(const NumericVector& x, const NumericVector& y) {
    const int n = x.size();
    NumericVector newval(n);
    newval(0) = y(0);
    newval(n - 1) = NA_REAL;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
      newval(i) = newval(i - 1) + (y(i + 1) - newval(i - 1))*(x(i) - x(i - 1))/(x(i + 1) - x(i - 1));
    }
    
    return newval;
  }"
)

dt <- data.table(
  x = c(1,3,4,5,8,12,13,20,21,25),
  y = c(1,1,2,2,8,2,4,6,5,5)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(iterInterp = dt[, newval := iterInterp(x, y)])
#> Unit: microseconds
#>        expr   min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval
#>  iterInterp 153.5 156.9 164.894  159.7 163.8 391.8   100

dt
#>     x y   newval
#> 1   1 1 1.000000
#> 2   3 1 1.666667
#> 3   4 2 1.833333
#> 4   5 2 3.375000
#> 5   8 8 2.785714
#> 6  12 2 3.757143
#> 7  13 4 4.037500
#> 8  20 6 4.879688
#> 9  21 5 4.903750
#> 10 25 5       NA
```

That comes out to < 3 minutes for 10M rows, except the overhead does not scale with the size of the `data.table`, as shown by benchmarking:

```
dt <- data.table(
  x = rep(c(1,3,4,5,8,12,13,20,21,25), 1e6) + 25*rep(0:(1e6 - 1L), each = 10),
  y = rep(c(1,1,2,2,8,2,4,6,5,5), 1e6)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(iterInterp = dt[, newval := iterInterp(x, y)])
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  iterInterp 157.585 159.0541 178.3298 168.0882 172.2245 274.102   100
```

That's a fraction of a second for 10M rows.

Comment: `Rcpp` would also have been my next recommendation when solving this with `data.table` isn't straightforward. +1

Comment: Terrific speed ! This is enough motivation to learn C++. By the way my production code needs `approxfun()` of R. By any chance is there a C++ replacement for the function? Anyway I have accepted your solution @jblood94. Also thanks @Waldi  for your efforts and thanks to @Henrik for the immediate red flag on the use of an inefficient `set`.

Comment: @LazarusThurston, example of integration of `approxfun` in `Rcpp` : https://stackoverflow.com/q/29463754/13513328

Comment: @LazarusThurston I'm curious as to why `approxfun` would be required, since it is simply performing linear interpolation, for which the formula (which you used in your question) is straightforward.

Comment: You are right,  i think I can live with the existing code instead of `approxfun`. However I do need to replace `y(i+1)` with the `k` rolling median of `y(i+n)` (the reprex used a simplistic value). I searched and found `qsort` as the C function for sorting and then take the centered value for median but can't make it work in my production code with RCPP. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing the rolling median inside the `Rcpp` function, do it for the `y` variable passed to the function. Something like `dt[, newval := iterInterp(x, MazamaRollUtils::roll_median(dt$y, 3L, 1L, "left", TRUE))]` (although it looks like you may also want to `shift` the rolling median before passing it--I'm just not sure exactly what you want).

Comment: A note on rolling medians: naive implementations can be very slow (e.g., using `frollapplly` took more than 2 minutes on a 10M-row `data.table` on my machine). The `seismicRoll` implementation is the fastest (~0.6 seconds). The `MazamaRollUtils` implementation is slightly slower but has `align` and `na.rm` arguments.